# Add Payload to Volley post request

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Volley as my http client library.
i need to send payload raw data as part of the request with Volley?
there are posts like: [How to send Request payload to REST API in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570656/how-to-send-request-payload-to-rest-api-in-java)

but how this can be achieved using Volley?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to use StringRequest as djodjo mentioned.
also getBody method need to be override - taken from here [Android Volley POST string in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057023/android-volley-post-string-in-body)

```
@Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    String httpPostBody="your body as string";
                    // usually you'd have a field with some values you'd want to escape, you need to do it yourself if overriding getBody. here's how you do it
                    try {
                        httpPostBody=httpPostBody+"&randomFieldFilledWithAwkwardCharacters="+ URLEncoder.encode("{{%stuffToBe Escaped/","UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "exception", exception);
                        // return null and don't pass any POST string if you encounter encoding error
                        return null;
                    }
                    return httpPostBody.getBytes();
                }
```

Comment: you don't need to do that. Volley can handle those. please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

check [the source and more info here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

**UPDATE: ** If you need to add params you can simply override `getParams()`

Example:

```
  @Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("param1", "val1");
      params.put("randomFieldFilledWithAwkwardCharacters","{{%stuffToBe Escaped/"); 
      return params;
    }
```

You don't need to override `getBody` yourself neither encode special chars as Volley is doing this for you.

Comment: String request indeed. you also need to override public byte[] getBody()

Comment: you dont . you did not specify what exactly you want. check the update.