# Doing a POST request with Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Hey I am looking to do a request like this in my android app:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --request POST --data "ON" http://example.com:8080/rest/items/wakeup
```

So far I have this:

```
String url = "http://example.com:8080/rest/items/wakeup";

    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MjpegActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //This code is executed if the server responds, whether or not the response contains data.
                    //The String 'response' contains the server's response.
                }
        },
            new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MjpegActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //This code is executed if there is an error.
                }
        }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MyData.put("AAAAAA", "BBBBBB"); //Add the data you'd like to send to the server.
            return MyData;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
}
```

This is taken from here: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/
Can someone help me figure out how to make this work? I know that the data I send goes where AAAAAA and BBBBBB are but I dont really understand how I can just send the string "ON".

Comment: What do you mean by string "ON" ? Can you please clarify it ? Do you want to know how to send parameters to this ?

Comment: See [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26270185/1270789), the second example. You probably just want `return String("ON").getBytes();` for `getBody()` rather than `getParams()`.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552242/sending-http-post-request-with-android

Comment: Excited to see someone asked question from my blog, any help is only from me :)

Comment: Why don't you just use Java's own HttpUrlConnection? Here is the best tutorial I found on the internet : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: @Ken Y-N Thanks that worked!

Comment: Also a relevant example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body

Answer (score 0):

Open a connection to the server port 80 and send this text( replace i.php with your file you want to post to )

```
POST /i.php HTTP/1.1
Host: denta.dev:8081
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 2

ON
```

Comment: Code to use Sockets in android is everywhere , example http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-client-implementation/