# Send Raw Data in android using Volley

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

I am trying to send an http post request with raw data .

may be its a duplicate question.. nut i've tried a lot but didn't get any exact solution..
May be there is some minor mistake that i'm not able to understand..

The raw data format is described below

```
{result_data: [project,circuit]}
```

what I'm doing:

```
public void MakeStrRawRequest(final String Tag, String url, final String appData, final ResponseListener responseListener) {

    //String uri = String.format(Locale.US, URL);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "String Success :" + response);
                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "String  Error In Request :" + error.toString());

                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                        try {
                            String res = new String(response.data,
                                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                            //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                            Logger.e(res);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("result_data", "[project,circuit]");
            // {result_data: [project,circuit]}
            return hashMap;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return appData.getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String AuthToken = "auto_token_value";
            headers.put(ApiConstant.TOKEN_KEY, AuthToken);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    ApplicationData.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}
```

Here is the response that i'm getting..

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400
```

I've tried both method to send data 
1.in getParam() and 
2. in getBody()

```
  1.   @Override 
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("result_data", "[project,circuit]");
        // {result_data: [project,circuit]} 
        return hashMap;
    } 

  2.
    @Override 
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return appData.getBytes();
    }
```

Comment: where you store data in appData variable?

Comment: Where have you add your raw data to sent to server?

Comment: @Mafujul Raw data is in String appData parameter

Answer (score 1):

getBody and getParams both are use to send parameters .So, You should call only one method at a time .If you want to send an **arbitary string** then use **getBody() method** and on the otherside if you want to **send normal parameters** then you should use **getBody()** method.For more detail you may see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057023/android-volley-post-string-in-body)